# empty list is returned from IMDB using python lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, imdb

I am trying to fetch top 250 movies list from IMDB using LXML but its returning empty list can tell me whats the mistake i have made.

```
from lxml.html import parse
tree = parse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
movies = tree.findall('.//table[2]//a')
```

movies list is empty []

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath doesn't correspond to any element in the linked page as I tested in browser using firepath ("no matching nodes" was returned).

**This is one way that worked for me :**

```
from lxml.html import parse
tree = parse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
movies = tree.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'chart')]//td[@class='titleColumn']/a/text()")
for movie in movies:
    print movie
```

Better use **`xpath()`** method which provide full support of XPath 1.0 expression. Brief explanation of the XPath parameter being used above is as follow :

- `//table[contains(@class, 'chart')]` : find `table` element, anywhere in the HTML document, which `class` attribute contains text `"chart"`
- `//td[@class='titleColumn']` : then find `td` element, anywhere within the aforementioned `table`, where `class` attribute value equals `"titleColumn"`
- `/a/text()` : then from such `td`, find child element `a` and return its text content

**Part of the above snippet output :**

```
The Shawshank Redemption
The Godfather
The Godfather: Part II
The Dark Knight
Pulp Fiction
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using a wrong XPath for parsing, using *Firebug* , the correct xpath for the movies table is

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody
```

This will return a table which contains all the movies data .

You will need some more processing to get each movie info .

I'd like also to suggest to use the requests lib for HTTP queries